# When to use kernel threads vs workqueues in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There are many ways to schedule work in the linux kernel: timers, tasklets, work queues, and kernel threads. What are the guidelines for when to use one vs another?

There are the obvious factors: timer functions and tasklets cannot sleep, so they cannot wait on mutexes, condition variables, etc.

What are the other factors in choosing which mechanism to us in a driver?

Which are the preferred mechanisms?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you said, it depends on the task at hand:

Work queues defer work into a kernel thread - your work will always run in process
context. They are schedulable and can therefore sleep.

Normally, there is no debate between work queues or sotftirqs/tasklets; if the deferred work needs to sleep, work queues are used, otherwise softirqs or tasklets are used. Tasklets are also more suitable for interrupt handling (they are given certain assurances such as: a tasklet is never ran later than on the next tick, it's always serialized with regard to itself, etc.).

Kernel timers are good when you know exactly when you want something to happen, and do not want to interrupt/block a process in the meantime. They run outside process context, and they are also asynchronous with regard to other code, so they're the source of race conditions if you're not careful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you choose between using a kernel thread and a work queue?

Comment: Well, the intent behind creation of the workqueues was that they would partially replace kernel threads as a means to schedule tasks in the kernel (lazy workqueues being the latest effort to deal with that) because at some point, the number of kernel threads in a box becomes costly to manage. With that in mind, I think I'd generally favour workqueues over kernel threads for most intents and purposes.

Comment: what is the problem tasklets resolved? i mean, tasklets run in intterupts context too, why not just do the work synchronized in the irq handler?

Comment: I don't think it makes a lot of sense talking about that right now, as they are in the process of getting removed.

Answer (score 36):

```
softirqs : deferred work runs in interrupt context
tasklets : deferred work runs in interrupt context
work queues : deferred work runs in process context

softirqs : Softirqs of the same type can run concurrently on several CPUs.
tasklets : Tasklets of different types can run concurrently on several CPUs, but tasklets of the same type cannot.
work queues : can run simultaneously on different CPU's

softirqs : cannot go to sleep
tasklets : cannot go to sleep
work queues : can go to sleep

softirqs : cannot be preempted/schedule
tasklets : cannot be preempted/schedule
work queues : maybe be preempted/schedule

softirqs : not easy to use
tasklets : easy to use
work queues : easy to use
```

Comment: actually, softirq's are infinitely scalable, that is they CAN run simultaneously on different CPUs: "Softirqs can run concurrently on several CPUs, even if they are of the same type. Thus, softirqs are reentrant functions and must explicitly protect their data structures with spin locks. Tasklets of the same type are always serialized: in other words, the same type of tasklet cannot be executed by two CPUs at the same time." see: http://www.91kaifa.com/doc/ulk/0596005652/understandlk-chp-4-sect-7.html

Comment: edit: The serialization is, of course, valid only for tasklets of *the same type*. "Tasklets of different types can be executed concurrently on several CPUs."

Comment: axeoth is correct. AND, a "work item" of the same type in a workqueue has can NOT run simultaneously on different CPUs since Aug 2012, because the workqueue is non-reentrant now: http://lwn.net/Articles/511421/

Answer (score 1):

Kernel threads form the basis for Work Queues. They are the only types of kernel helper routines that run within the process context.