# i2c device driver. System down when try to send data

Tags: c, linux-kernel, structure, i2c

I trying to write i2c device driver and all is gone fine:

1. device detected successfully
2. device in sysfs class with value attribute created too
3. then I init a hrtimer and start it
4. I am trying to send data from store function of attribute and it's work fine

but when I trying to send data from hrtimer callback function my system going down. Here is some code (i was remove incudes, defines and non-important code):

**led-indicator.h**

```
struct timer_job {
        ktime_t period;
        struct hrtimer timer;
        ...
};

struct ledindicator {
        struct i2c_client *client;
        struct device *device;
        struct timer_job job;
        int value;
};
```

**led-indicator.c**

```
include "led-indicator.h"
static struct ledindicator *li;

// device attribute [value] store function
static ssize_t value_store(struct device *device, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buffer, size_t count)
{
    int val;
    kstrtoint(buffer, 10, &val);
    li->value = val;
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(li->client,  0xBA, 0x02); // this is work fine
    LOG("New value is %d \n", li->value);
    return count;
}

//timer callback, fire each timer_job.period
static enum hrtimer_restart send_next(struct hrtimer * tim) {
    long start = jiffies;
    struct timer_job *job = container_of(tim, struct timer_job, timer);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(li->client, 0xBA, 0x02); // this cause system fault
    hrtimer_forward_now(tim, job->period);
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

//when device is detected I am create sysfs device and init timer. 
enter code here//Also I am crate led_indicator structure and save i2c_client pointer for future use
static int li_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    int ret = 0;
    li = kmalloc(sizeof(*li), GFP_KERNEL);
    li->client = client;
    li->value = 0;

    ...
    // here creating device and attribute for it
    ...

    hrtimer_init(&(li->job.timer), CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

    li->job.timer.function = send_next;
    li->job.period = ktime_set(1, 0); //1 sec
    hrtimer_start(&(li->job.timer), li->job.period, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

    return ret;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I think I am understand what is wrong. I cannot use any function which use active and maybe passive delays (like msleep or in this case i2c_smbus_write_byte_data).
I need to use tasklets or workqueue. Correct?

Comment: One way to find out is to set the hrtimer but do nothing in the handler but printk().  Once that works you could add the I2C reads/writes.  I'm doubting this delay would crash the kernel here, though.

Comment: Without i2c send it's work fine. If I am add msleep or i2c send it's cause system fault.

Comment: Can you try the I2C send routine in a read or write dispatch call?

Comment: How I can do this? ;-)

Comment: You can add read and write dispatch functions to your driver, then make a device node and then open the device from a test app in user space and read/write to it.  Alternatively, you can create a proc entry and invoke a proc handler by echo-ing something to it from a shell prompt.  That might be easiest/fastest.

Comment: I had a sysfs device and attribute for it. So I was put i2c_smbus_write_byte_data in store function (value_store) - it's work correctly I was wrote about it in my question. So I can do 
**echo  128 > /sysfs/class/../value**
and driver send it fine. I think problem is what i2c_smbus_write_byte_data use some delays and it's cause system fault. I will try to use workqueue from timer callback

Comment: So tasklets too cause system fault. But workqueue is work fine.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps your theory about faulting after doing a sleep in the I2C code may be correct.  BTW, this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147299/when-to-use-kernel-threads-vs-workqueues-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to questions. Instead, post an answer and accept it.